# Why can't I echo using an img tag?

Tags: php, image

I'm trying to echo my uploaded image from database using img tag and php variable. I've tried this code but it does not display the image at all,
but the other code works fine, the original of the path of the image is https://localhost/admin/uploads

here is my query for file upload and print screen of my code and output,[move to upload file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0UHP.jpg),[fetching image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loKD5.jpg),[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQ9Sb.jpg)

```
      if($query_run)
  {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["emp_image"]["tmp_name"],'/uploads/'.$_FILES["emp_image"]["name"]);
    $_SESSION['success'] = "Employee Record Added";
    header('Location: create.php');
  }
```

here is my code to fetch the image

```
<?php
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run))
        {
    ?>
<td><?php echo $row['id']?></td>
<td><?php echo '<img src="uploads/'.$row["emp_image"].'" width="100px;" 
                 height="100px;" alt="Image"/>'?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['s_name']?></td>
```

Comment: Right click on the broken image, open it in another tab and show us the path

Comment: And also show us the actual path where the image is stored

Comment: Is the image tag rendered at all when you inspect the page in devtools? Are you getting a 404 for the image path in the chrome devtools network tab?

Comment: http://localhost/admin/uploads/Transparency-Logo.jpg path of the brocken image

Comment: What is the actual path of the image?

Comment: it's in the upload folder stored it using this code move_uploaded_file($_FILES["emp_image"]["tmp_name"],"uploads/.".$_FILES["emp_image"]["name"]);

Comment: Try this `src="../uploads/'.$row["emp_image"].'"`

Comment: Change the path in source and tell whats happened

Comment: still the image does not load

Comment: Check the path again. The issue is with your path

Comment: Your web server's _document root_ (ie `http://localhost/`) will point to a directory in your filesystem. Which directory is that? What is the full path to the `uploads` directory within your filesystem?

Comment: http://localhost/admin/uploads

Comment: **_"...in your filesystem."_**, ie `C:\Users\something`, `/var/www/html`, etc

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\uploads

Comment: @jon B yes I'm getting a 404 error for the image path but I've checked the query and I've inputed the correct file path of the image

Comment: If you're getting a 404 it is either an incorrect path or a permissions issue

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good. You should checkout something...

1. Is output of `'uploads/'.$row["emp_image"]` actual path name of image file?
2. Remove `;` in `width="100px;" height="100px;"`
3. Check query and check in emp_image image path is correct or not.

Comment: the emp_image path is correct its uploaded in the uploads folder and i've check the uploads folder and i see there the image that i uploaded

Comment: You can use 'https://localhost/admin/uploads/' . $row["emp_image"] and double quotes makes some confusions as @sanjun-dev said.

Comment: `<td><img src="https://localhost/admin/uploads/<?php echo $row["emp_image"] ?>" width="100px;" height="100px;" alt="Image"/></td>`

Answer (score -1):

Better use like this.

Note: First you have to print the `$row["emp_image"]` then ensure the path is correct.

```
<td><img src="uploads/<?php echo $row["emp_image"]; ?>" width="100px;" 
             height="100px;" alt="Image"/></td>
```

I am confusing with the single quotes and double quotes between your code. so better use this way.

Comment: still the image does not load

Comment: can you please try to `<?php var_dump($row["emp_image"]); ?>` inside your loop?

Comment: Then copy paste the path in your browser, after the current url

Comment: Please explain what you've changed and why. Shouldn't the given code render to the exact same markup?